# How to run Databricks Notebook 1 to Notebook 2 using widgets in Scala:

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I create a widget that will hold the value following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/widgets) with Python. But I require to create widgets and run data bricks from notebook 1 to Notebook 2 using Scala.

how can I do this using scala?

would appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the exact requirement is? What is the purpose of your widgets here

Comment: Hi Saideep, I'm trying to run a Databricks notebook from another notebook. I am providing widget as a input.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run notebook 1 to the inside of notebook 2 use the below code:

First, I create widgets in my notebook 1

```
%scala

dbutils.widgets.text("name1", "<sample_name>")
val  w1 = dbutils.widgets.get("name")
```

[image]

Then after as per [MS_doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/notebook-workflows#scala) run notebook 2.

**Code:**

```
%scala
val  timeoutSeconds = 60
val  result = dbutils.notebook.run("./<notebook_path>",timeoutSeconds, Map("widget"  ->  "w1"))
```

[image]

**Another approach:**

Using `%run ./<notebook_path>`  you can run notebook that contain widgets

For more information refer to this [MS_Doc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/widgets#--use-databricks-widgets-with-run)